# How to implement Round Shaped AppBar with Gradient Background in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, gradient, flutter-appbar

I want to achieve an AppBar which has a rounded bottom radius and gradient background. Also, I need to place some other content like cards within AppBar using the bottom property.
Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const Toddly());

class Toddly extends StatelessWidget {
  const Toddly({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Toddly',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 158, 77, 130),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
              child: const CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/profilePicture.png'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          title: const Text(
            'Julia',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Nunito',
            ),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications_outlined),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
            ),
          ],
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(150.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              color: Colors.white,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text('Some content'),
            ),
          ),
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                colors: [
                  Color(0xFF72326a),
                  Color(0xFF321c53),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
              bottom: Radius.circular(30.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFfef1ee),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I used the shape property to implement rounded bottom AppBar.
I did gradient background using flexibleSpace.
And, I used bottom to add my other content under within AppBar.

However when I run all above code. rounded bottom appBar is not working.
[image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1aga.jpg)
And, if I remove flexibleSpace it is showing, but I lost my gradient.
[image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5WA1.jpg)

Please, help me to figure it out and is it possible to do that without creating custom AppBars since I saw several approaches.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you just need to **add corner radius to gradient container** as well attaching you the updated code.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const Toddly());

class Toddly extends StatelessWidget {
  const Toddly({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Toddly',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 158, 77, 130),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
              child: const CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/profilePicture.png'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          title: const Text(
            'Julia',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Nunito',
            ),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications_outlined),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
            ),
          ],
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(150.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              color: Colors.white,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text('Some content'),
            ),
          ),
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
              bottom: Radius.circular(30.0),
            ),
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                colors: [
                  Color(0xFF72326a),
                  Color(0xFF321c53),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
              bottom: Radius.circular(30.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFfef1ee),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Here's screen shot]